# Is there a way to know a visitor is coming from a Starbucks?

Tags: ip

AWS publishes its own IP range: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

I was wondering if I could obtain the same for Starbucks establishments.

The end goal is to ban Starbucks customers; I already have a ban on Mac OS user agents which is close.

Comment: ... Are you trying to ban all hipsters?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I have not laughed that hard in a while!

Comment: How will knowing what IP addresses are assigned to Starbucks help you identify Starbucks customers?

Answer (score 8):

There's no reliable public list of IP addresses for Starbucks Wi-Fi, nor is there any reliable way to determine if an IP address corresponds to Starbucks Wi-Fi.

After Starbucks (at least in the US) switched from AT&T to Google for Wi-Fi service, Google has been providing the service via any available ISP, whether Google owned or not.

For example, the local Starbucks Wi-Fi provided by Google is run on a Comcast Business cable connection. There's no way to distinguish its IP address from any other Comcast Business customer.

Therefore, in order to ban Starbucks customers, you will need a fairly large IP address range:

```
0.0.0.0/0
```

If you block this range, it's guaranteed to block all Starbucks customers.  (And everyone else.)